# How to customize the window title bar of an Electron app?

Tags: macos, electron

I'm getting started working with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) to build a desktop app. How can I customize the window title bar (which contains the close, minimize, and full screen buttons) to add custom views? Safari is an example that I am thinking of:

[image: safar title bar]

Comment: You may check [http://photonkit.com/](http://photonkit.com/)

Comment: @AlessandroLoziobizBisi Woah! That's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hide the default titlebar by creating a frameless window:

```js
// main.js
window = new BrowserWindow({
    titlebarStyle: 'hidden',
    trafficLightPosition: {
        x: 15,
        y: 13,  // macOS traffic lights seem to be 14px in diameter. If you want them vertically centered, set this to `titlebar_height / 2 - 7`.
    },
})
```

Then create your own makeshift titlebar using HTML + CSS:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<body>
    <header class="titlebar"></header>
    ...
</body>
```

```css
/* styles.css */
.titlebar {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;    /* Allow user to drag the window using this titlebar */
    -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Prevent user from selecting things */
    user-select: none;
}
```

#### The result so far:

[image: Scroll bar overlaps titlebar]

**Notice that the titlebar appears under the scrollbar. It even moves when the user scrolls.** We need to separate it from the scrollable content by wrapping everything below the titlebar in a `<div class="main-content">` and then adding these styles:

```css
.main-content {
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);  /* Force the content to take up the viewport height minus the titlebar height */
    overflow: auto;              /* Allow the main content to be scrollable */
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;            /* Make the HTML body be non-scrollable */
}
```

#### Final result:

[image: Scrollbar appears below the titlebar]

Now you can add whatever HTML content you want up there.

Answer (score 30):

Your only option in Electron would be to create a [frameless](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window) (aka borderless) window, and then create a "fake" title bar with CSS, including any UI elements you need.

Electron/webkit provides CSS properties that allows you to make any element draggable, like a titlebar:

```
.titlebar {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

The first, and cross-platform option is to create a [frameless window](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/frameless-window/). The second is macOS only, and allows you to hide the title bar, but retain the window controls, allowing for the addition of custom buttons.
Example:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

// This will create a window without titlebar, allowing for customization
let win = new BrowserWindow({ titleBarStyle: 'hidden' })
win.show()
```

Then you could use the css properties `-webkit-user-select` and `-webkit-app-region` to specify the drag zone.